# Problem with OData query in Microsoft Flow for GetItems action on a SharePoint list having 20000+ rows

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have created a Microsoft Flow (PowerAutomate), to retrieve records from a SharePoint list. The list has 22,300 records in it. I have written the below OData filter query. The column (Email) is of Person type.

Email/EMail eq 'me.someone@company.com'

But none of the records are retrieved. However, if I give the below query, the same record is retrieved.

ID eq 22102

The list contains the below records.

| ID | Email |
| --- | --- |
| 22102 | Me someone |
| 2 | another person |

However, if I query for the email id of the 2nd record (another.person@company.com), it is retrieved fine.

Email/EMail eq 'another.person@company.com'

I am wondering is there any limitation towards retrieving records greater than 20000? Really surprised why the second record is retrieved and not the first one? Or do I have to tweak any pagination settings?

When retrieving using ID, it works fine, while for Person, it is not. Is there any indexing I need to enable for query to work beyond 20,000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having more than 5000 items with this person/email "me.someone@company.com", filter condition will fail. This is the limitation of SharePoint and SharePoint REST APIs.

If you have less than 5000 items for this particular email/person, you can try below suggestions:

1. Add indexing on this person or group column
2. Add 5000 in Top Count in Get items action
3. Enable pagination from settings of Get items action and provide number of items you want to fetch.
4. You can fetch maximum of 100000 items using Get items action.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ganesh.. but the filter condition is not failing but it is not retrieving any record. However, the record count with this email id is just 1, so I did not see a need to add pagination. The query I give just fetches 1 but seems strange that I am not getting this record. I will try the indexing suggestion definitely.

Comment: In that case, indexing and adding Top Count should work for you.

Comment: Really strange but what worked was adding TopCount as 30000 and providing pagination as 5000, as per your suggestion. I tried indexing but it did not work. But still wondering why, even though I had only 1 result record, the top count is playing a role here.. Though this time, the time taken to run the flow is ~25s compared to 1s previously. Maybe it just took first 250 records for search when I ran without pagination and topcount. But, thanks a lot for your solution. Happy it worked..